# Powershell: Passing command options forward slash changing to backward

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the invoke (ii) command to open an access database that has command line options. What I would like to have executed is below (yes there is a space in the name of the access database). The database is in the same folder as the Powershell script.

What I want: `program name.accdb /cmd Rester`

What I get:  `program name.accdb \cmd Rester`

The exact commands I am using are:

```
$Path_To_EXE = "program name.accdb /cmd Rester"
&ii $Path_To_EXE
```

I am new to Powershell and have done some searching but can't seem to find an answer. I can create a work around by creating a separate .bat file but that seems like going backwards.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is `/cmd` supposed to be doing here? What is that a flag to? I don't think the embedded spaces in that argument are going to work correctly for you (unless that whole string is, together, an executable item.

Comment: The /cmd option is passed to Access and is used in the Access VB code for various settings. I have the entire name in quotes, is there something else you recommend to make it an executable item?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a VBA script while passing it a parameter with powershell:

```powershell
$aApp = New-Object -ComObject access.application
$aApp.Application.OpenCurrentDatabase("some program.accdb")
$aApp.Application.Run("VBAScriptName", [ref] "Raster")
```

First according to [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209207) you can use ;; for /cmd from the command line. Second because of the way call quotes and dequotes variables you have to include the /cmd flag separate from the variable (well, its the easiest way). Third, you might consider creating a new com-object to handle running Access with Powershell as it allows for a lot more options (just ask and I can add some examples of this). This being said try:

```powershell
$Path_To_EXE = "program name.accdb"
&ii $Path_To_EXE ;;Rester #Try ;;"Rester" if it doesn't work.
                          #if that works then its a problem in Rester
#fyi another way is:
$Path_To_EXE = @("program name.accdb", ";;Rester")
&ii $Path_To_EXE
```

If you want to use an ActiveX Object Controller to open and perform operations on Access look at [this blog from technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/15/how-can-i-add-a-record-to-a-database-using-windows-powershell.aspx) <- Read the link there are pitfalls to avoid.

```powershell
$adOpenStatic = 3
$adLockOptimistic = 3

$objConnection = New-Object -com "ADODB.Connection"
$objRecordSet = New-Object -com "ADODB.Recordset"

$objConnection.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Scripts\Test.mdb")

$objRecordset.Open("Select * From Computers", $objConnection,$adOpenStatic,$adLockOptimistic)

$objRecordSet.AddNew()
$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("ComputerName").Value = "atl-ws-001"
$objRecordSet.Fields.Item("SerialNumber").Value = "192ATG43R"
$objRecordSet.Update()

$objRecordSet.Close()
$objConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea however it still isn't working. Perhaps these com.objects you mentioned might work.I am getting an error in Powershell ,when I used the @("program name.accdb", ";;Rester") suggestion, Powershell opens the program however then tries to open a separate program called Rester - which it can't find. Adding ;;"Rester" seems to just echos Rester and not pass it along. Thoughts?

Comment: that's what /cmd does -> it runs a specific command after access is closed, so the question is "What specfically are you trying to do? (edit your original question with "Update: What I'm trying to do......" if its a long explaination.

Comment: I am passing Access a command line variable that is uses when it opens & runs. Access takes items after the /cmd and passes it to the command() function. It is not used after Access closes in our situation. It works via batch files and on the cmd line. In our batch file the exact line is Start /MAX "" "C:\Users\%filelocation%\Documents\Validation Software\Program Name.accdb" /cmd Raster

Comment: @Shiva If you just want to pass a parameter to a VBA script in Access - see my updated answer (first one works for me with a simple VBA script)

Answer (score 3):

You should also give a shot to the start-process cmdlet :

```
$Path_To_EXE = "c:\program.exe"
#Notice the simple quotes ...
$Arguments = @( "name.accdb",  '/cmd' , "Rester" )
start-process -FilePath $Path_To_EXE -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait
```

I'm not quite sure of the format of the answer you'll get tough ...
for database interaction, I'll rather use JGreenwell's Approach, since the answer that you'll get will be much easier to read/debug ... 
Let me know if it works.